# Mapping multiple values to an array object

Tags: array, swift

I've reached a point in an application where I need to initialize some coordinates to an array and I wound up using nested for-in loops to accomplish the task.

Is there is a better way to accomplish this?

```
class Coord {

    let xVal : Int
    let yVal : Int

    init(x: Int, y: Int) {
        xVal = x
        yVal = y
    }
}

var coord = [Coord]()

for xVal in 0...20 {
    for yVal in 0...20 {
        coord.append(Coord(x: xVal, y: yVal))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is fine. If you wanted to use a functional approach and avoid making `coord` be mutable you could use `flatMap` and `map`:

```
let indexes = 0...20
let coord = indexes.flatMap { (xVal:Int) -> [Coord] in
    indexes.map { (yVal:Int) -> Coord in
        Coord(x: xVal, y: yVal)
    }
}
```

If you are familiar with lambda expressions then you may know that this can be simplified to this:

```
let indexes = 0...20
let coord = indexes.flatMap { x in indexes.map { Coord(x: x, y: $0) } }
```

If all you are doing with Coord is storing coordinates, you may consider just using Tuples:

```
let coord = indexes.flatMap { xVal in indexes.map { yVal in (xVal, yVal) }}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping for, thank you kindly

Comment: Great explanation!